# Libcurl и статическая линковка RTLIBCFG=static

Tags: c, curl, lib

В инструкции по установки Libcurl под Windows Visual Studio, сказано, что:

> ### Статическое связывание Microsoft C RunTime (CRT):
>
> Если вы используете mode = static, nmake создаст статическую сборку
> и свяжется с ней.   libcurl, но * не * статической CRT. Если нужно, вы
> можете заставить nmake связать   в статической CRT, передав RTLIBCFG =
> static. Обычно вам не следует использовать   эта опция, и nmake по
> умолчанию будет использовать DLL CRT. RTLIBCFG используется редко   и
> поэтому редко тестируется. При передаче RTLIBCFG для конфигурации,
> которая   был уже построен, но не с этой опцией, или если опция была
> указана   иначе вы должны уничтожить каталог сборки, содержащий
> конфигурацию, чтобы nmake мог построить ее с нуля.

-Я что то не понимаю, что значит, что сначала "mode = static, nmake создаст статическую сборку
и свяжется с ней." и сразу, что:

"Если нужно, вы можете заставить nmake связать   в статической CRT, передав RTLIBCFG =
static."

-Что в данном случае подразумевается под static CRT и DLL CRT ?
-И что в итоге будет создано, если не указать - RTLIBCFG = static ?

PS:Я конечно попробовал без RTLIBCFG = static, но результат не совсем понял.

Comment: Ну примерно, что cURL подтянется статически (в EXE'шник), а вот сама рантайм-библиотека — нет. Так понятнее?

Comment: @Harry, то есть будет зависеть от наличия Виндосовских DLL ?

Comment: Не "виндосовых", а установленного рантайма С++.

Comment: @Harry, то есть - это, что то типа, если скомпилирую exe-шник в Debug режиме и перенесу - этот exe-шник на другой компутер, на котором не установлена Visual Studio - то этот Debug exe-шник не запустится ? То есть этот Debug exe-шник - как бы динамически связан со всеми не обходимыми файлами Visual Studio ? Ну как то так, очень упрощенно ?

Comment: @Harry, это, как раз в эту тему, что, когда устанавливаешь, какое то ПО или игры, установщик некоторого ПО говорит, что для работы нужно установить пакет VSC++, что то типа этого. Если так, правильно я понимаю тогда, что ну к примеру VS2019 - debug режим компилирует с динамическим связыванием c CRT, а release - со статическим связыванием CRT ?

Comment: Да, это рантайм VS, его можно ставить отдельно. А по debug/release — это все настраиваемо.

Comment: @Harry, позвольте еще один вопрос: вот собрал я библиотеку в данном случае libcurl со статическим CRT. И вдруг подумалось, а зачем ? Ведь я все раввно libcurl или что то другое будут подключать к своему проекту и его компилировать, а компилироваться в exe-шник он уже все равно будет со статическим CRT. А тут тогда получается два статическим CRT - и наверное это в том числе двойной размер файла итоговый получится + может конфликты между двумя этими статическим CRT будут при итоговой линковке ? Или я все не правильно понял ?

Comment: Нет, в вашей библиотеке сам рантайм лежать не будет, только ссылки на него. Библиотека — это по сути просто собранные в один файл объектные файлы.

Comment: @Harry, ну то есть фактически, я просто могу в свойствах итогового проекта выставить, как я понял вот эти "флаги" отвечающие за это - MD и MT, а в подключаемых библиотеках - этого смысла в этом плане тогда делать - нет ?

Comment: Видите ли, а если компилятор сам рантайм вызывает по-разному? Если в нем как-то заранее прошивается, что это будет статическая библиотека? Я бы не рисковал :)